# Freeze on boot after installing Yosemite

Tags: macos, install, startup, error

Sorry for the writing style but I am typing from my smartphone now.

My MacBook pro on Mavericks worked like a charm but crazy as I am I decided to install Yosemite without any backup as I am lacking space on all my drives now.

It took some time to install Yosemite (I was said it was even unresponsive for a while). I started this morning and tonight after work I could use it, it seemed to work fine but after activating Trim Enabler, I have been trying to reboot unsuccessfully. The apple logo displays with a progress bar that stops halfway then the logo is replaced by a barred circle.

In verbose mode it says various messages then "Still waiting for root device" but as I said I could play with Yosemite so it must exist somewhere right? May there be something wrong with the boot table?

I resetted the PRAM, tried the recovery mode and check & repair the disk, and to reinstall the OS (but it cannot retrieve info about my computer => please contact Apple Care WHAT?)

Is there anything I can do from the terminal? I am really stuck cos I do not have a clue what I could do more.

Thanks for helping! :-)

Comment: I would suggest, since it's a beta and your only Mac (as it seems) to have portioned your hard drive first, but it's a bit late for that. I'm no expert, and it seems you've tried everything I would've tried. However, do you have a bootable CD or thumb drive of an old OS? You might try booting off that by holding C during startup. You may also try booting from another computer with Firewire (which you probably don't have) by holding Option. Good luck!

Comment: If anyone has a fix, please let me know since a friend of mine and I are also experiencing a startup freeze on Beta 1.

Comment: I have another MBP but this morning I tried to clone the faulty Macintosh HD into another drive, and could boot from it. After work I will try to do it the other way around and hope it will be fine!

Comment: same here. Yosemite on early 2011 MBP15, worked fine for 5 days until this morning. It cannot boot up, verbose showed with the same error as yours.

Comment: @안우선 check this if you've recently enabled TRIM support on a 3rd party SSD. http://www.cindori.org/forums/topic/heads-up-osx-10-10-beta-no-go/

Comment: @Matt3o12 I've got a fix if you've previously enabled TRIM support on a 3rd party SSD. please refer to my last comment.

Comment: Many thanks, I actually found the solution by myself today at 2 am, after spending so much time trying to fix my computer, so did not take time to comment my question B-) The solution is here : http://www.cindori.org/trim-in-os-x-yosemite

Comment: @ss1271 Thanks, you I already installed a clean copy.

Comment: I've read on Twitter that booting into safe mods once helps finish the installation and solves this problem. Have you tried it ?